# Xamarin forms value converter causing infinite loop

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get a simple two way binding example working with a converter but as soon as the value in the entry changes for example if you enter 1 it gets stuck in an infinite loop, it gets to the end of the ConvertBack method and sets the value correctly. It then hits the ConvertBack method again except this time with the value 11, the next time it will be 111 and just keeps going until it crashes the emulator.

Even when I stop debugging, the emulator just keeps entering the number into a new search window infinitely.

Converter:

```
public class StringToNullableInt : IValueConverter
{
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            int tmp = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out tmp))
            {
                return tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        return value;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Field to bind

```
public int? Test
    {
        get
        {
            return _test;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _test)
            {
                _test = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Test"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Bound Field

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource cnvStringToNullableInt} }" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind a Int to an Entry is not a good solution (for me).

I suggest to have a TestString property

```
string _testString {get;set;}
public string TestString {
    get{
       return _testString;

    }
    set{
        try {
            _testString = value;
            _test = int.Parse(_testString);
        }
        catch {    _test = null;}
    }
}
```

now you can try to bind with TestString, without IValueConverter

Comment: I used int as an example but if i change it to strings i get the exact same loop issue. any time i use two way binding with a converter the way I have done in the example it seems to be happening